# convert a file in SVG to an image

Tags: java, batik

Hello, I would like to use Batik to convert a file in SVG to an image and I would use the library batik transcode if you have an example + Netbeans not accept me these instructions

```
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;
```

If you are familiar with Batik, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What happens when you try importing the library with `import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;`? Any error messages?

Comment: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist

Comment: Well, that's your answer then! See [installation instructions here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/install.html)

Comment: it does not work can you tell me the link

Comment: there are several link I do not know what exact link

Comment: What link are you looknig for? The files for downloading? You can try this: http://apache.mirrors.spacedump.net/xmlgraphics/batik/

Comment: okk thank you,I have a Question can you explain these instructions JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder(); t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY, new Float(.8)); String svgURI = new File(args[0]).toURL().toString(); TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI); OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("out.jpg"); TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream); t.transcode(input, output);

Comment: If you are looking for a programming tutorial, I think you will have better luch on another site! Stack Overflow is great for specific questions when you get stuck, though. The code you pasted there does the acutal conversion from the file given in 'args[0]` to `out.jpg`, it seems.